# JavaScript checking passwords

Tags: javascript, html

HTML:

```
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="vorname">Vorname</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="vorname" onkeyup="createLoginName();" placeholder="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="nachname">Nachname</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nachname" onkeyup="createLoginName();" placeholder="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="loginname">Loginname</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="loginname" placeholder="" disabled>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="passwort">Passwort</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="passwort1" onkeyup="char_count();" placeholder="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="passwort">Passwort wiederholen</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="passwort2" onkeyup="char_count(); checkPassword();" placeholder="">
    </div>
    <p><span id="feedback"></span></p>
    <button type="submit" id="registrieren" class="btn btn-primary">Registrieren</button>
 </form>
```

JavaScript:

```
checkPassword();

function checkPassword(){
  var inputPasswort1 = document.getElementById("passwort1").value;
  var inputPasswort2 = document.getElementById("passwort2").value;
  if(inputPasswort1 != inputPasswort2){
    document.getElementById("registrieren").setAttribute("disabled", "true");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("registrieren").setAttribute("disabled", "false");
  }
}
```

I tried different things already but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas or suggestions?

With **console.log(inputPasswort1 + " " + inputPasswort2);** I checked both variables but they are okay, I get the correct values.

https://jsfiddle.net/t8hx3wk7/4/

Comment: You forgot to write your question

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 document.getElementById("registrieren").disabled = true;
 document.getElementById("registrieren").disabled = false;
```

Instead of

```
document.getElementById("registrieren").setAttribute("disabled","true");
document.getElementById("registrieren").setAttribute("disabled","false");
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/t8hx3wk7/7/)

```js
    function checkPassword(){
      var inputPasswort1 = document.getElementById("passwort1").value;
      var inputPasswort2 = document.getElementById("passwort2").value;
      if(inputPasswort1 != inputPasswort2){
        document.getElementById("registrieren").disabled=true;
      } else {
document.getElementById("registrieren").disabled=false;
      }
    }
```

```html
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="passwort">Passwort</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="passwort1" onkeyup="checkPassword();" placeholder="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="passwort">Passwort wiederholen</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="passwort2" onkeyup="checkPassword();" placeholder="">
    </div>
    <p><span id="feedback"></span></p>
    <button type="submit" id="registrieren" class="btn btn-primary">Registrieren</button>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.removeAttribute('disabled')` instead of `.setAttribute('disabled', false)`, or as said before, `.disabled = false`